How would you clean this greenish mold on this outside wall prior to fixing the crack?
I am about to fix this crack then paint it. I do need however to clean it let it dry and get it proper for the fix. What is bugging me is the best way to get rid of this greenish and sometimes brown mold ? what would your suggestions be? any other ideas on how to properly clean and prepared the area would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance

The standard solution for cleaning the exterior of a house is a 50/50 mix of bleach and water.  Try Outdoor bleach. It is formulated to be safer for plants.
Spray the mix on and scrub with a stiff brush. Rinse with clean water.  If the stain is stubborn, let the mix sit for 5-10 minutes before scrubbing.
Always let the cleaned area dry thoroughly for a day or 2 before repairs and painting.
